# Print lines if difference matches the condition

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Print lines only if the difference between column 2 values is 10000 or greater

Input File

```
1   176506  C
1   176566  T
1   188778  C
1   189699  M
1   199878  T
1   259923  H
1   268859  C
1   346868  J
1   349825  K
1   356882  U
1   396293  L
```

Output

```
1   176506  C
1   188778  C
1   199878  T
1   259923  H
1   346868  J
1   356882  U
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To find difference between two rows of a same files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/376144/to-find-difference-between-two-rows-of-a-same-files)

Comment: Why is the last line not included? `396293 - 356882 = 39411 > 10000`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's basically "send me teh codez"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your values are increasing and that you want to print a line if the difference between the last-printed-line and the current line exceeds a threshold:

```
awk -v n=10000 '$2 - p >= n { print; p = $2 }' infile
```

Output:

```
1   176506  C
1   188778  C
1   199878  T
1   259923  H
1   346868  J
1   356882  U
1   396293  L
```

Comment: I tried this method but it was not working, the input i have shown here is part of a big file, i have edited my input file with some more entries and from that using the command given here it should print line "1 356882 U", but it is skipping that line and printing "1   396293  L" and hence all following entries are changed, can you please explain the possible reason for the same.

Comment: Does it work now?